Issues with Ceedling unit testing in a project with FreeRTOS dependency
I am currently working on a project that involves unit testing using Ceedling, Unity, and CMock. My project has a dependency on FreeRTOS, specifically using functions like xTaskNotifyWait() from FreeRTOS.h.
Problem:
I encountered an issue where Ceedling cannot build the tests due to a missing reent.h file, which is included by FreeRTOS.h. The error message I receive is:
FreeRTOS/Source/include/FreeRTOS.h:84:14: fatal error: reent.h: No such file or directory
   84 |     #include <reent.h>

Setup:
The reent.h file is located in my STM32CubeIDE toolchain directory at:
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.9.0/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/arm-none-eabi/include
My project.yml is configured for Ceedling, Unity, and CMock.
Here’s a snippet of my project.yml:
---

# Notes:
# Sample project C code is not presently written to produce a release artifact.
# As such, release build options are disabled.
# This sample, therefore, only demonstrates running a collection of unit tests.

:project:
  :use_exceptions: FALSE
  :use_test_preprocessor: TRUE
  :use_auxiliary_dependencies: TRUE
  :build_root: build
#  :release_build: TRUE
  :test_file_prefix: test_
  :which_ceedling: gem
  :ceedling_version: 0.31.1
  :default_tasks:
    - test:all

#:test_build:
#  :use_assembly: TRUE

#:release_build:
#  :output: MyApp.out
#  :use_assembly: FALSE

:environment:

:extension:
  :executable: .out

:paths:
  :test:
    - +:TDD_Tests/**
    - -:TDD_Tests/support
  :source:
    - Core/App
    - Core/App/EEPROM
    - Core/App/Executor
    - Core/App/FrequencyInvestigation
    - Core/App/VoltageInvestigation
    - Core/App/LWIP
    - Core/App/ModbusTCP
    - Core/App/OPCUA
    - Core/App/RegisterData
    - Core/App/SPI1
    - Core/App/SPI3
    - Core/App/System
    - Core/App/USART2
    - Core/App/USART3
    - Core/App/HourCounter
    - Core/Inc
    - Core/Src
    - FreeRTOS/Source
    - FreeRTOS/Source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F
    - FreeRTOS/Source/portable/GCC/MemMang
    - FreeRTOS/Source
    - FreeRTOS/Source/CMSIS_RTOS
    - FreeRTOS/Source/include
    - Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc
    - Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src
    - Drivers/CMSIS/Include
    - Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include
    
  :support:
    - TDD_Tests/support
  :libraries: []

:defines:
  # in order to add common defines:
  #  1) remove the trailing [] from the :common: section
  #  2) add entries to the :common: section (e.g. :test: has TEST defined)
  :common: [] #&common_defines []
  :test:
    #- *common_defines
    - STM32F407xx
    - TDD_TEST_ACTIVE
    - USE_HAL_DRIVER
    - UA_ARCHITECTURE_FREERTOSLWIP
    - USE_FULL_LL_DRIVER
  :test_preprocess:
    #- *common_defines
    - TDD_TEST_ACTIVE

:cmock:
  :mock_prefix: mock_
  :when_no_prototypes: :warn
  :enforce_strict_ordering: TRUE
  :includes:
    - stm32f4xx.h
  :plugins:
    - :ignore
    - :expect_any_args
    - :array
    - :callback
    - :return_thru_ptr
  :strippables:
    - ['(?:WRITE_REG\s*\(+.*?\)+)']
  :treat_as:
    uint8:    HEX8
    uint16:   HEX16
    uint32:   UINT32
    uint32:   long unsigned int
    int8:     INT8
    int16:    INT16
    bool:     UINT8

# Add -gcov to the plugins list to make sure of the gcov plugin
# You will need to have gcov and gcovr both installed to make it work.
# For more information on these options, see docs in plugins/gcov
#:gcov:
#  :reports:
#    - HtmlDetailed
#  :gcovr:
#    :html_medium_threshold: 75
#    :html_high_threshold: 90

:gcov:
    :html_report: TRUE
    :html_report_type: detailed
    :html_medium_threshold: 75
    :html_high_threshold: 90
    :xml_report: TRUE

    :gcovr:
        :abort_on_uncovered: false

#:tools:
# Ceedling defaults to using gcc for compiling, linking, etc.
# As [:tools] is blank, gcc will be used (so long as it's in your system path)
# See documentation to configure a given toolchain for use

:flags:
  :test:
    :compile:
      :*:
        - -Wall
        - -Wextra
        # Extra flags to avoid cast warnings in the HAL library
        - -Wno-int-to-pointer-cast 
        - -Wno-pointer-to-int-cast
        - -Wno-error=address

# LIBRARIES
# These libraries are automatically injected into the build process. Those specified as
# common will be used in all types of builds. Otherwise, libraries can be injected in just
# tests or releases. These options are MERGED with the options in supplemental yaml files.
:libraries:
  :placement: :end
  :flag: "-l${1}"
  :path_flag: "-L ${1}"
  :system: []    # for example, you might list 'm' to grab the math library
  :test: []
  :release: []

:plugins:
  :load_paths:
    - "#{Ceedling.load_path}"
  :enabled:
    - stdout_pretty_tests_report
    - xml_tests_report
    - module_generator
    - gcov
...


What I’ve Tried:

Adding the include path directly in project.yml.
Using environment variables to manage the include paths.
Creating a local include directory and copying necessary headers there.

Despite these efforts, I still encounter issues with Ceedling recognizing the reent.h file.
Request:
Could someone guide me on how to properly configure Ceedling to handle this dependency? Is there a best practice for managing such dependencies in a Ceedling project?

Have you tried it like this:
:paths:
  :test:
    - +:path/to/test/
    - -:path/to/test/support
  :source:
    - +:path/to/source/**
  :include:
    - +:path/to/source/**
    - +:path/to/reent/**
  :support:
    - path/to/test/support/

The double asterisk (*) could also help with your :source: list.
So in your case:
:paths:
  ...
  :include:
    - +:C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.9.0/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/arm-none-eabi/include/**

On an unrelated note I would try to modify that path if possible.
If that does not work you could try it like that tutorial is describing it in section Including other header files in our mocks
:cmock:
  ...
  :includes:
    - <reent.h>
  :treat_externs: :include

